# getting foreach is not a function when using select multiple in angularjs even if I am not using foreach

Tags: angularjs, select

when I researched many people get this error by using `select multiple` and I am the same too. You can see the error below. I am not using foreach loop at all. It's going inside angularjs script and in there, it's causing error. I am using select multiple 5 times in the same page, but only this clientele list showing the error. When I compare the array with other arrays which are not causing errors, everything is the same. Any solution from you guys?

**clientele array**

```
[
{
    clienteleId:1,
    name:"Hey"

},
{
    clienteleId:2,
    name:"Hey2"

} 
]
```

**js code**

```
 <select style="overflow:auto;" multiple class="form-control m-b" size="10" ng-model="selectedClientele"
        ng-options="clientele.name for clientele in availableClienteles"
        ng-dblclick="selectClientele(selectedClientele)">
        <option>Select</option>
 </select>
```

**error**

```
js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:38564 TypeError: a.forEach is not a function
    at nh.p.writeValue (js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:38746)
    at hh.e.$render (js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:38761)
    at js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:38761
    at m.$digest (js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:38589)
    at m.$apply (js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:38592)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:38726)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:5187)
    at HTMLSelectElement.elemData.handle (js?v=JvBJIyzkDFnuWdUC12a6IwAf_1-tX5vI--RGCM0TLVg1:4995)
```

Comment: I am not sure that the error comes from the code snippets you provided.